# Enabling the numeric keypad on Devastator II keyboard?

Tags: numpad

Kudos to the folks on the led answer using `xset led on`.  On the same keyboard, Cooler Master Devastator II, the numeric key pad doesn't work.  I tried `showkey -a` and type them all. Only key working is the Enter key.
Intel® Core™ i5-2500K CPU @ 3.30GHz × 4 5. running ubuntu 16.04

Comment: OOps.  Mis read the assistive tech answer.  Turned off Mouse Cursor movement in settings-universal access-...

Comment: Thanks! Just read your comment to turn off mouse cursor movement. Numpad works now :)